# tel:{phonenumber} link in adaptive card not working in channel in Microsoft teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, tel

I have used search extension query based command in Microsoft teams to render result set And as a result set Adaptive card is getting displayed. On click of a button on adaptive card I have added tel link

```
      {
        type: 'Action.OpenUrl',
        title: 'Call Mobile',
        url: `tel:${contact.phone_number}`,
      },
```

The link is working fine if I click it from chat section but it is not working fine if I click from channel section. PFA screenshots for the same
[image]

Comment: We are also able to repro this issue, we are checking internally. Meanwhile could you please check this deeplinks document. If this might help you - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-an-audio-or-audio-video-call

Comment: Thanks Meghana, I'll look into it. Also an update for this, the link is not working only from channel section on web and native app. Seems to be working on mobile(Android and IOS).

Comment: We have raised a bug for the same, we will keep you posted on the updates.

Comment: Hey any update on this?

Comment: Currently we do not have any update/ETA to share, we will keep you posted.

Comment: Engineering team has confirmed that "tel:" by design is NOT supported by desktop and web.