# tel:{phone_number} link [Action.OpenUrl] not working on web in adaptive card microsoft teams from Chat

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, tel, action-button

We have added a button of type **Action.OpenUrl** in adaptive card and its url as a **tel link** as given below.

```
"actions":[
  {
     "type":"Action.OpenUrl",
     "title":"Call Mobile",
     "url":"tel:+919090909095"
  }
]
```

It was apparently working fine few days back but have stopped working suddenly.
If we add any valid url as any like this,

```
"actions":[
  {
     "type":"Action.OpenUrl",
     "title":"Call Mobile",
     "url":"https://www.google.com/"
  }
]
```

It works fine but our requirement is to open our phone app hence the tel link.
We already raised the same issue from [channel section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72261665/telphonenumber-link-in-adaptive-card-not-working-in-channel-in-microsoft-team), but from chat it was working fine earlier.

Comment: Could you please share your adaptive card payload?

Comment: Hi I have updated the payload above, please check

Comment: We have already raised a bug for this. We will let you know once we have any updates on it.